# App-Website Communication for Ionic/vue.js App

Tags: architecture, web-applications, application-design

Currently I am designing a cross-platform mobile app using Ionic and vue.js.

That app enables users to create a game, add players and play rounds. When the game is played, a score for each player will be kept.

Now I want to enable the functionality to show this score via a web-application, so it can be shown on a projector when people play it or something similar. For this, I am planning to put up a simple web-application.

If the app administrator requests it (game is played in person, only one app running per game), the app should show a link to the website (+ some custom id) where the current score is rendered. If the score changes, the rendered score on the website should change as well.

How should this best be implemented? I thought about using a webhook on the web-app that the app can send the score to, but maybe a persistent connecting between app and website is better for the continuous updating? Or is there a way to do this without hosting this otherwise useless website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Database to store your players and their score and you need to provide some APIs for the following cases:

- Register User
- Score Submission
- Leaderboard
- Get User Detail & Score

You can implement those APIs easily by using [Python Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) and submit the scores after each round. Then you can present any kind of queries on every platform. But you need DB and API for addressing your requirement.

**Update**

**DB Model**

Only one table is required for the start.

| User |
| --- |
| String unique_id |
| String nick_name |
| int score |

**Register User**

You can have a simple registration API like this :

URL: http://api.your-game.com/register
**Request Payload**

```json
{
"user_id": "unique-device_id",
"nick_name": "it could be anything and doesn't need to be unique"
}
```

For having a unique device id in Ionic : [Read More](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/unique-device-id/)
You can also generate some UUID.

**Response Payload**

```json
{
"user_id": "unique-device_id",
"status": "User registered successfully"
}
```

**Score Submission**

URL: http://api.your-game.com/submit
Payload

```json
{
"user_id": "unique-device_id",
"score": 100
}
```

**Response**

```json
{
"user_id": "unique-device_id",
"status": "score submitted successfully !"
}
```

**Get User Score**

URL: http://api.your-game.com/user/score

**Request Payload**

```json
{
"user_id": "unique-device_id"
}
```

**Response**

```json
{
"user_id": "unique-device_id",
"score":200,
"nick_name": "MaFi",
"status": "success"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was planning not to have a registration flow so far, but simply let the user "create" players by entering their names and over the game associating score increments with them. There is no need to save players over several games and likewise no need to track there scores over several games. I was also wondering if I could "get away" without a database, simply using some in-memory data structure like a python dictionary. Do you have a specific recommendation for an API design?

Comment: User experience is very important and I really appreciate your way of thinking to let the players enjoy the game without headache. 
But I see no limitation to achieve your desired UX with good architecture and reliable design. for example when we talk about Registration of the user, it doesn't mean the user needs to provide username,password and email. The only thing that we need to inform the backend that we have a new user. I will update the details on my original answer due to charachter limitation.

Comment: And I forgot to say about in-memory solutions, It's possible but the effort/cost is almost the same as using persistent DB and the output is not flexible and reliable. But you can check "Redis" as a solution, I don't recommend you to use this solution.